# How to get access to uri image in adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions

Help me please. I have the error below when I try to use setImageUri in adapter after reopen application.

java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10159 and Uri android.resource://com.example.cocktailsmyapp/...

My Adapter

```
class CocktailAdapter constructor(private val fragment: Fragment) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CocktailAdapter.CocktailHolder>() {
    private var listCocktails = mutableListOf<com.example.cocktailsmyapp.domain.models.Cocktail>()
    private val cocktailModel: CardCocktailViewModel by fragment.activityViewModels()

    inner class CocktailHolder(val binding: ItemCocktailBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CocktailHolder, position: Int) {
        with(holder) {
            val cocktail = listCocktails[position]
            binding.apply {
                val contentResolver = fragment.activity?.contentResolver
                contentResolver?.takePersistableUriPermission(Uri.parse(cocktail.image.toUri().toString()), FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                imageView.setImageURI(cocktail.image.toUri())
                titleCocktail.text = cocktail.title
                imageView.setOnClickListener {
                    cocktailModel.setCocktail(cocktail)
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_cocktailCardFragment)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): CocktailAdapter.CocktailHolder {
        val binding =
            ItemCocktailBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return CocktailHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listCocktails.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setCuisineList(listCocktails: ArrayList<com.example.cocktailsmyapp.domain.models.Cocktail>) {
        this.listCocktails = listCocktails.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

    <application
        android:name= ".app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CocktailsMyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Add new item with uri image (I got uri from PickVisualMedia())

```
class AddCocktailFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddCocktailBinding
    private val cocktailModel: AddCocktailViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val adapterIngredient = IngredientAdapter()
    private val permissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
            uri?.let {
                binding.imageAdd.setImageURI(it)
                cocktailModel.setImage(it.toString())
            }
        }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddCocktailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observeState()
        binding.buttonIngredient.setOnClickListener {
            showPopUpDish()
        }
        binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            saveCocktails()
        }
        binding.buttonCancel.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
        binding.imageAdd.setOnClickListener {
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }
    }

    private fun saveCocktails() {
        cocktailModel.apply {
            val title = binding.titleAddCocktail.text.toString()
            setTitle(title)
            val description = binding.descriptionAddCocktail.text.toString()
            setDescription(description)
            val recipe = binding.recipeAddCocktail.text.toString()
            setRecipe(recipe)

            addCocktail()
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerIngredients() {
        binding.apply {
            val linerManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            tagButtonsRecycler.layoutManager = linerManager
            tagButtonsRecycler.adapter = adapterIngredient
            adapterIngredient.setIngredientsList(cocktailModel.ingredientsList.value as ArrayList<String>)
        }
    }

    private fun observeState() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            cocktailModel.ingredientsList.collect {
                initRecyclerIngredients()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showPopUpDish() {
        val popup = PopUpIngredientFragment()
        popup.show((this).parentFragmentManager, "showPopUp")
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        permissionLauncher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
    }
}
```

I set uses-permissions into Manifest but it doesn't work. I try to use ContentResorver but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Who gave you that uri? Where does that image reside? Taking persistable uri permission every time in an adapter looks the wrong place and moreover cannot be done for a resource. The image view cannot handle your -wrong- resource uri. So where did you get it from?

Comment: Please tell the whole uri and tell where you get it from.

Comment: I add class AddCocktailFragment in the Question. I get uri for new cocktail in class AddCocktailFragment  and then save to Room. But when I reopen app I can't open image by setimageUri which I get from Room.

Comment: You did not tell the whole uri. Nor did you tell where you got the uri from. Nor what this uri has to do with a resource.

Comment: PickVisualMedia() will not deliver an uri that starts with 'android.resource..`.

Comment: Take persistable uri permission you should do in that fragment the moment you got the uri.

Comment: `permissionLauncher` Wrong confusing name at it is a pickVisibleMediaLauncher.

Comment: `I get uri for new cocktail in class AddCocktailFragment ` Wrong answer that tells us nothing. You got uri from PickVisualMedia().

Comment: permissionLauncher Wrong confusing name at it is a pickVisibleMediaLauncher. – 
blackapps - I agree with you.